# Lower bound on comments

Tags: feature-request, comment, character-limit

I wish the comments didn't have a lower bound for characters.Many times all I want to say is "yes". Can someone explain me what is the purpose of this l.b.?

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked (and answered) before. The closest thing I could find was http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/what-is-the-etiquette-about-leaving-short-thank-you-comments

Comment: Apropos of tag: If you are asking for an *explanation of purpose*, then this is *support* or maybe *discussion*. If you were asking for the limit to be changed or removed, that would be a *feature request*.

Answer (score 8):

This is the site humbly suggesting you to use more characters. I'd like to also encourage you to do this. And also to consider the following observations:

1. Users who habitually type things like "n-mfld", "height fcn", "cohomol", "sing. coho", " Lebesgue meas."...  are making the site harder to use for others: these abbreviated keywords will not come up in search.
2. Users who habitually omit punctuation and ignore capitalization rules are making the site look less professional.
3. Users who habitually post incomplete questions, lacking in explanation of notation and terms in the question, are wasting the time of those who read and try to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Situations warranting a simple "yes" or "no" exist, but they should be in the extreme minority.  Discussions here should be more in depth than that.  Comments are not a chat room. The limit exists to remind users to write good content, and the inconvenience of being unable to leave short comments pales, in my view, to a potential decrease in overall quality due to its removal.

Comment: Yes. $\hphantom{Sorry, could not resist.}$